# Identify all forms using Requests and Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm doing this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import requests

website='http://www.website.ro/'
r=urllib.request.urlopen(website).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')
form=soup.find('form')
print(form)
```

Say that website only contains 1 Form and what i'm interested in is:

```
<div class="search">
```

Namely, the name/names of the form/forms.
Next, what i want is to pass this forms to Requests.post and get the response.
How can i do that?
As to the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) for Requests,

```
r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
```

The first argument for requests.post is a **url**. Is there any way to get the url the form triggers by knowing the form name or from r.text?

For example, mechanicalsoup's method **select_form** does not need a url, it uses the form name. (I don't want to use mechanicalsoup)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you would have to look at what requests were fired manually via something like Chrome Developer tools and then use that URL.